# Can't correctly read response of API call (JS)

Tags: javascript, http-status-codes

I'm calling an API and getting results back as expected in JavaScript. If a 400 status is returned, I call another API, which I'm doing with an if statement. However, this "if" is never triggered, I think because the way my response is getting read. My code is:

```
 var getSearchPrimary = {
                    url: 'SEARCH_URL',
                    type: 'POST',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    context : this,
                    cache : true,
                    timeout: 60000,
                    success : function(e) {
                        status = JSON.stringify(e.status.code);
                        if(status === "400"){
                            console.log("failed");
                            this.getSearchSecondary(query);
                        }else{
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
                        }
```

In this case, when I do `console.log(status);`  I get `"400"` so I'm really not sure why my if statement is never firing!

The response is:

{"status":{"code":"400","message":"Error: No results match the query"},"response":{"results":""}}

I've been staring at this a while now, and would really appreciate any insight!!

Comment: your console log returns 400 as string or int? Because you're using strict comparison `===`. Try using just `==`

Comment: Interesting-- I just tried replacing (status === "400") with if (!(e.response.length)) and that does fire.

Comment: I had tried just `==` , but that didn't solve anything.

Comment: just log what the status variable has, and check the datatype so that you can compare it correctly.

Comment: Print JSON.stringify(e) result in the question please.

Comment: Sure, just added it.

Answer (score 1):

The "success" method is called when the request is successful. When 400 is returned, that's not a success. Use the "error" property instead to provide a function that is executed when the request fails.